# graphql failed Error In PWA-Venia Theme

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa-studio, graphql

Hi Guys I'm getting error while running **yarn run build** error and Screenshot is attached in below. Help will be appreciated, Thanks :)

[image]

```
FetchError: request to http://magento2/graphql failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND magento2 magento2:80
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/magento2/pwa-studio/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  message:
   'request to http://magento2/graphql failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND magento2 magento2:80',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND' }
Hash: 82f799d2ec3be1983d77
Version: webpack 4.29.6
Time: 8685ms
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, 
Sorry to disturb everyone.
I got a solution.
I was forget to give full url in .env for

## Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name.

MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=http://magento2.com/